# PHP Show specific record from database that matches the id number

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, record

I have a db table 'order_form' and all records are displayed in a page.(I use dreamweaver.) In one of the records, contact no, i made a link Send SMS. If I click that,it should link to a page where i can send that number an sms.basically,the contact no should be displayed in the textfield and should match the one that belongs to the id num. How to do that?

The Send SMS link looks like this and it already displays the matching id num at the url. My probblem is binding the matching contact no which belongs to that id num. I hope I described it right.

```
 <td><a href="index.php?transaction_num=<?php echo $row_orders['transaction_num']; ?>">Send SMS</a></td>
```

[image]

After clicking Send SMS, it goes here and should display the matching contact no. in the Recepient textfield.

[image]

*NOTE i'm using transaction_num instead of id num.just to let you understand easily i used id num to ask here.

Comment: So, did you try to write some code?

Comment: @u_mulder don't know how to do it.i use dreamweaver.I just want to display the matching contact no in the recipient textfield

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'value'`

Comment: does that same table have a field holding the tel no? if not it should be in some other table, you have to SELECT that row and get mobile no, using id_num, and set it in the textbox

Comment: good idea is to share table(s) schema

Comment: @Yazan yes it's in the same table. I don't know how to display the contact no in the recipient textfield

Comment: @u_mulder the contact no will depend on whose id num was clicked

Comment: @kim check the answer below, this could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the same table have the mobile no, say the field name is `order_mobile_no`, then change the Send SMS link code to the following:

```
<td><a href="index.php?order_mobile_no=<?php echo $row_orders['order_mobile_no']; ?>">Send SMS</a></td>
```

and in the sending page, add this at the input of the mobile no field (recipient):

```
<input type ="text" name="xxx" id="xxx" value="<?php echo $_GET['order_mobile_no']?>" />
```

name and id = xxx, i am not sure what is that input is named.

**EDIT:**
to avoid that error, you need to check if that param is exist in the URL,
which is done using `isset()`, so the `<input...` tag should be :

```
<input type ="text" name="xxx" id="xxx" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['order_mobile_no'])){echo $_GET['order_mobile_no'];}else{echo "";}?>" />
```

Comment: wait after sending the form it's giving me <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: contact_no in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\MCC\admin_sms.php</b> on line <b>84</b><br />

Comment: whats in line 84? in that page? and did you change the name after the `?` in the grid page? `...?contact_no=<?php echo $row_orders['order_mobile_no']; ?>` in the Send SMS link

Comment: sorry , i might be miss-understood, this error happens when you click Submit? ignore previous comment then,

Comment: line 84 is this line <input type ="text" name="xxx" id="xxx" value="<?php echo $_GET['order_mobile_no']?>" />
I already changed it to <input name='recipient' type='text' value="<?php echo $_GET['contact_no']?>">

Comment: i told you, you have to change xxx to the proper name, could be `contact_no`.

Comment: yes,when i click submit,it doesn't send the sms and i get that error inside the recipient textfield

Comment: just replace xxx with the original name & id of that field, mostly it should be `contact_no`

Comment: yes it was already replaced when i ran the page. <input name='recipient' type='text' value="<?php echo $_GET['contact_no']?>">

Comment: how do i define this line? $_GET['contact_no'] so that the error disappears

Comment: now i got it, the issue is, sometimes that param is not sent (when you press submit, i will edit the answer, just ignore all comments and check for the edit.